# Idiom/metaphor for a constant figure in a certain place

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, metaphors

I was wondering if there were any idioms or cliched metaphors commonly used to describe someone who you can always expect to see in a certain place because they spend a lot of time there (or even better, creative metaphors!).

And more specifically, I am looking to describe a chessmaster who's always chilling in the break room at the chessboard.

Perhaps phrases containing 'perennial tree' or 'rock' or 'staple'? But I can't quite arrive at a good metaphor from them. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: I'd say "fixture" is a relatively literary figurative usage in such contexts. Something like *He's a **regular** at the local chess club* is more likely in ordinary conversational contexts.

Comment: That individual is "*part of the furniture*" in colloquial UK English

Comment: Hello, Jenny. Creative metaphors don't really fit in with the ELU template, and are probably better asked for on Writing.SE.

Comment: @Richard Thank you!! I love this expression. It would fit perfectly for the situation I want to describe.

Answer (score -2):

You can also call him/her **"an adornment"**.

As per https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adornment

Definition of adornment

1 : the action of adorning : the state of being adorned
2 : something that adorns

Comment: I don't see how that fits. Did you follow the links to the meaning of "adorn"?